# Jdbc compilation using Ant

Tags: oracle, ant, sqlplus

I am using the following ant script for jdbc compilations.

```
<sql driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.184.133.133:1521:SUPP"
userid="${UsernameB}"
password="${PasswordB}"
onerror="continue"
delimitertype="row"
delimiter="/"
keepformat="yes">
```

I have a file with the following content:

> create OR REPLACE synonym CIVWS for CIVW;
>   /

compilation of the above is failing with the following error.

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00911: invalid character
```

I understand that the delimiter is / and hence the semi colon after the sql statement has caused the issue. There are hundreds of files like this, all will compile properly in sqlplus. However fail with jdbc. I cant change the code now. Is there any work around for this. I cant change the delimiter to ; also. Please suggest.

Comment: Those lines are wrong for SQL*Plus as well. The `/` will execute the last statement ("the buffer") resulting in the `crete or replace` run twice in SQL*Plus. If you use `create synonym` instead of `create or replace` you will actually get an error (object already exists)

Answer (score 0):

1. first you could try to use `... delimiter=";" delimitertype="row" ...` and make sure that the pl/sql blocks containing ";"s are separated by some ";" on a single line (with only a newline following it immediately - thus triggering the execution of it as a single statement).
2. if you can't add the ";" by hand, try to copy the source files to some tmp dir and try to change them there by hand or by some automated regexp replacement (e.g. using ant copy task with a regexp replace filter).
   (e.g. replacing lines matching `^(.*end\s*;?)(.*)$` by `\1\n;\n\2` could be enough if you are lucky)
3. another solution for inserting the ";"-single line delimiters could be to put these blocks in separate files (maybe automated) and execute them via the `<sql><transaction src="<yoursqlfile>.sql" /> <!--...--> </sql> <!--...-->"` ANT task.